# 1 hyperlinks, Multiple Options in HTML (css)

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm looking for a way that I can link 2 (or more) HTML files to 1 hyperlink. They shouldn't open simultaneously, but the code should choose 1 randomly to open.

I am using  .

I hope someone can help.

I have looked online on solutions, but I didn't find anyone talking about it. Or maybe I didn't use the right words to look it up.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, inside an a tag you can use only one src..... you can use js to add it randomly... but you have to try yourself and the ask here posting your attemps. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location to redirect the browser to a given url picked randomly among many

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS or HTML. In order to randomize something you can use JS.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/mB7eG/) of what you can do:

**JavaScript**

```
// Your links in array
var links = [
    "www.link1.com",
    "www.link2.com",
    "www.link3.com",
    "www.link4.com"];

openLink = function () {
    // preventDefault() on an <a> tag
    event.preventDefault();
    // random number between 0 and the number of links
    var randnum = Math.random() * links.length;
    // round random number to use as an array index
    randnum = parseInt(randnum, 10);
    window.location(links[randnum]); // open link
};
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="openLink();">Go to random website</button>
```

Comment: Can I use these links as HTML files? When I use 10.1.html (my file name) as the link, it doesn't link to that page but just stays on the original one.

Comment: I am also using the <a> function, because I need to do that with an image (that also changes when you hover over it)

Comment: @ZebMingus try `window.location` instead of `window.open`, also make sure the JS file is in the same folder where the 10.1.html is located.

Comment: @ZebMingus if you are using `<a>` tag with `href` attribute, probably you need to add `event.preventDefault();` in `openLink` JS function to prevent opening the link. Edited my answer.

Comment: And what do I put in the 'href'?
Also: if i add the 'onclick="openLink();"' inside the '<a>', it doesn't do anything :-/ 

Thank you so much for helping me btw!:)

Comment: @ZebMingus Just realized that `onclick` doesn't work with `<a>' tag, can you use '<button>' tag instead?